# Product of two matrices is zero.

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $B$ be $(l \times m)$-matrix with maximal rank $l$, $l<m$. Let $A$ be $(m\times m)$-matrix, and let $BA=0$. Then $dim(nul(A))\geq l$.

Proof(?). $BA=0 \Longleftrightarrow im(A)\subseteq nul (B)$. But $dim(nul(B))=m-l$ and $dim(im(A))=m-dim(nul(A))$. So $m-dim(nul(A)) \leq m-l$ or $l\leq dim(nul(A))$.

Is it correct?

Comment: yes this is perfectly correct!